# iterate over the rows , and control count i++

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for method, that iterates over the rows, but apply some method only for every 20th or 30th row values
so something like:

**UPDATED CODE**

```
for index, row in df.iterrows(), index=+20:
     location= geolocator.reverse("%s, %s" % (row['lat'],row['long']),timeout=None)
      row['location']=location.address
      time.sleep(3)
return df
```

Actually I try to minimize the number of requests, cause otherwise I have the timeout issue. That's why I tried iterate over the rows, and apply the function of request only for every 20th or 60th row (cause I have 7000 rows) and not to speed the process by applying the time.sleep method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just slice the df using `iloc` and a step param:

Example:

```
In [120]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':np.random.randn(30)})
df

Out[120]:
           c
0  -0.737805
1   1.158012
2  -0.348384
3   0.044989
4   0.962584
5   2.041479
6   1.376785
7   0.208565
8  -1.535244
9   0.389831
10  0.049862
11 -0.142717
12 -0.794087
13  1.316492
14  0.182952
15  0.850953
16  0.015589
17  0.062692
18 -1.551303
19  0.937899
20  0.583003
21 -0.612411
22  0.762307
23 -0.682298
24 -0.897314
25 -0.101144
26 -0.617573
27 -2.168498
28  0.631021
29 -1.592888

In [121]:
df['c'].iloc[::5] = 0
df

Out[121]:
           c
0   0.000000
1   1.158012
2  -0.348384
3   0.044989
4   0.962584
5   0.000000
6   1.376785
7   0.208565
8  -1.535244
9   0.389831
10  0.000000
11 -0.142717
12 -0.794087
13  1.316492
14  0.182952
15  0.000000
16  0.015589
17  0.062692
18 -1.551303
19  0.937899
20  0.000000
21 -0.612411
22  0.762307
23 -0.682298
24 -0.897314
25  0.000000
26 -0.617573
27 -2.168498
28  0.631021
29 -1.592888
```

This will be much faster than iterating over every row

So in your case:

```
df['C'].iloc[::20] = some_function()
```

should work

Comment: seems good! but I don't want to make process faster, I updated the question, maybe you know how ti face this issue

Comment: Well I don't know why you get the timeout issue, I would look at that as an issue as my answer is vectorised and will be much faster than iterating row wise

Comment: well, I suppose the problem is that server is limited by the number of request per some period of time, that's why I put time.sleep at the end of every iteration

Comment: following the logic of your example I applied this method as ```location= geolocator.reverse("%s, %s" % (df['lat'].iloc[::20], df['long'].iloc[::20]),timeout=None)
    df['location'].iloc[::20] =location.address``` that throws me ```
ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point```

Comment: That is an issue with your func not understanding the Series, you'd have to do `df.iloc[::20].apply(lambda x: geolocator.reverse(str(x['lat']), str(x['long']), timeout=None), axis=1)`

Comment: thank you, I will upvote your answer as one that works but the problem of service timed out still persists

Comment: I think you can just assign `row['location']=df.iloc[::20].apply(lambda x: geolocator.reverse(str(x['lat']), str(x['long']), timeout=None), axis=1)` it should work but the timeout issue is a separate problem

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
for index, row in enumerate(df):
    if index % 20 == 0:
        # do something
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `enumerate` and the modulus operator:

```
for index, row in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    if not index%20:
        row['C']=some_function()
return df
```

I took the `return` out of the loop so that the loop wouldn't end after one iteration.

Comment: seems good, but it throws ```TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str```

Comment: That means `row` is a `tuple` rather than the dictionary-like structure (indexed with string keys) you're expecting. I don't know `pandas`; sorry.